# Iterating through txt file over interval; Python TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, integer

I have txt files filled with a column of time values and a column of potential (V) values. I am trying to record the V value every 1 hour (timestep) with t0 = 2 hours and tf = 12 hours. I have not seen this error before and do not know where it is coming from. Any help optimizing the code would be appreciated.

```
def bisection(array,value):
  '''Given an ``array`` , and given a ``value`` , returns an index j such that ``value`` is between array[j]
  and array[j+1]. ``array`` must be monotonic increasing. j=-1 or j=len(array) is returned
  to indicate that ``value`` is out of range below and above respectively.'''
  n = len(array)
  if (value < array[0]):
    return -1
  elif (value > array[n-1]):
    return n
  jl = 0 # Initialize lower
  ju = n-1 # and upper limits.
  while (ju-jl > 1): # If we are not yet done,
    jm=(ju+jl) >> 1 # compute a midpoint with a bitshift
    if (value >= array[jm]):
      jl=jm # and replace either the lower limit
    else:
      ju=jm # or the upper limit, as appropriate.
    # Repeat until the test condition is satisfied.
  if (value == array[0]): # edge cases at bottom
    return 0
  elif (value == array[n-1]): # and top
    return n-1
  else:
    return array[jl],jl

def scatterBisect(txtfile,start,end,interval):
  t_vals = txtfile[:,0]
  V_vals = txtfile[:,1]
  
  t_points = []
  V_points = []

  t = bisection(t_vals,start)[0]

  while t <= end:
      i = bisection(t_vals,t)[1]
      V_points.append(V_vals[i])
      t = bisection(t_vals,t + interval)[0]
      t_points.append(t)

  return t_points, V_points

x,y = scatterBisect(H_M_5a_purple,2,12,1)

plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Here is the full error traceback:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-1eff7c030470> in <module>()
     17   return t_points, V_points
     18 
---> 19 x,y = scatterBisect(H_M_5a_purple,2,12,1)
     20 
     21 plt.scatter(x,y)

<ipython-input-33-1eff7c030470> in scatterBisect(txtfile, start, end, interval)
     11       i = bisection(t_vals,t)[1]
     12       V_points.append(V_vals[i])
---> 13       t = bisection(t_vals,t + interval)[0]
     14       t_points.append(t)

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: When asking about an error, show the full error with its traceback.  You (and we) need to know exactly where the error occurs.  According to the error you are trying do something like `x[1]`, but `x` is a integer, not a list or array.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your response. I am new to Stack Overflow and appreciate the feedback. Does the added error traceback help you identify the problem in my code?

Comment: If `bisection` returns an `int`, why are you doing `bisection()[0]`? What do you expect to happen there?

Comment: Both function are your own code, yes? `bisection` is documented starting out: `Given an ``array`` , and given a ``value`` , returns an index j` And it does appear that this is how you want the function to work. Taking that into consideration: what exactly are you expecting the line of code `t = bisection(t_vals,t + interval)[0]` to *do*? You get an index (i.e., an integer) back from the `bisection` call, and then attempt to subscript that as if it were a list, which it isn't. Is the error, then, *surprising*?

Comment: It seems as though you changed your mind partway through and decided that `bisection` should return a pair of values - the index, and the corresponding value in the input sequence; but it only does this in some cases (look at the `return` statements), and disagrees with the documentation. I think you should stick to returning only the index. If you need the corresponding value, the caller can just index into the original sequence again.

Comment: I've modified bisection to return the value at the index, as well as the index. So when I call bisection()[0], I am trying to get the appropriate value from my txt file.

Comment: `bisection` has multiple `return` statements.  Only one returns a tuple,